# Right click in Firefox selects/highlights html elements...why?

Tags: html, firefox, contextmenu, right-click

I have built a custom context menu but have found annoyingly that **when I right click on my site in firefox text and images just seem to randomly get selected.**

The link below is a basic html dump of the page that is having issues. You can see that when you right click it in Firefox, certain elements are highlighted. Very annoying! This must be a purely html markup problem in Firefox as there is absolutely no CSS or JS on this page.

**Example Here:**
http://pastehtml.com/view/1e16jup.html

Love to hear your thoughts/suggestions...

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of errors in this page have a look at the validator [result here.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://pastehtml.com/view/1e16jup.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Maybe it gives firefox a lot of problem rendering the page properly.

Close all the `<meta>` and `<img>` tags, `<script>` must have proper type attributes, tags like `<h1>` shouldn't be placed inside of `<a>`, `<p>` neither.

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems 99% of the errors are due to the use of custom attributes. I will have to replace them with the html5 data attribute instead. Do you believe that that is the issue though? What is the proper syntax for closing meta and img tags? My template is based on the html5 boilerplate.

Comment: I thought at the beginning that it was the issue, but the more I browse on invalid website and none of them has your issue. The right click seems to select the element and any of its child. It's really weird.

Comment: I guess I will have to break it down until I identify the cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean the HTML5 contextMenu? Because this is not implented in any browser.

Comment: No jQuery context menu. That is beside the point anyway. If you right click anywhere on the example page I gave it highlights the children of the element you have right clicked on. This is not normal behaviour and is not evident on other sites.

Comment: "This must be a purely html markup problem in Firefox as there is absolutely no CSS or JS on this page."

Nonsense. It has both. And weird malformed tags.

Comment: Sorry in this example I forgot to exclude the css and JS tags. Considering they are pathed relative to my site they wont be found in this external example. I have tested without and the problem is still there. Must be to do with HTML markup. Could you please provide a little insight into the where the malformed tags are?

Comment: Just to mention that Firefox is now adding support for the HTML5 native 'context menu' (declared through markup). It's now available in Firefox 8 beta. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_8_for_developers).

Answer (score 0):

A bit of quick investigation seems to demonstrate that the header+footer elements have this behaviour. Also, lists appear to have it as well. This is because those elements have a certain semantic use and this behaviour seems consistent with those semantic uses. Check out the specification to see how these elements are intended to be used.

I'm firing blind but I'd suspect you can override this with -moz-user-select - but this is going contrary to the Firefox user experience. I wouldn't recommend it at all.